# Rails - compare two numeric fields, find the smallest and then compare with the users value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple search setup in which someone enters values and then I pass the values as params to my search model.

I have two fields - standing_capacity and seated_capacity.

I'd like to conduct a where search so that it looks at the standing and seated capacity (both fields may not contain a value) of a record and it finds the smallest of those two values. It would then use this value and compare it against the value that the user has entered. If the capacity is higher than what the user entered then it would return the venue.

Is this possible using a where search? Or would it be better to have a hidden_field that contains the smaller of the two numbers?

Edited to answer some of comments below:

The user adds the minimum_value using a very basic form.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :minimum_capacity %>
    <%= number_field_tag :minimum_capacity, params[:minimum_capacity], placeholder: "Min Capacity (numbers)", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

It then goes to my very simple controller:

```
def industry_directory
    @industry_users = @industry_users.where("seating_capacity <= ?", params[:minimum_capacity]) if params[:minimum_capacity].present? 
    end
```

That above would give me my venues if I was only looking at the seating_capacity but I don't know how to compare the seating and standing capacity first and then take the lowest value to use against the param.

Comment: show you model and controller codes

Comment: Could you give us a bit more context around what your application is trying to do? And also what you have written so far?